# How do I change between two JTables?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

So I have a JTable inside a JScrollPane inside a frame that works. What I want to do is to change the table that is being showed to another table that displays some other information and has more/less columns/rows. How do I do this?

I have tried stuff like putting another table in the ScrollPane but that doesn't work and if I re-put the ScrollPane in the frame it disappears.

EDIT:

I think this is all the code that has to do with this problem. I simply call the funktions to change the view.

```
    Object[][] userData = new Object[50][6];
    userTable = new JTable(userData, new String[] { "Namn", "Adress", 
            "Telefon", "Personnummer", "PIN", "Antal cyklar" }) {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    userTable.setSelectionMode(0);
    userTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    Object[][] bikeData = new Object[50][7];
    bikeTable = new JTable(bikeData, new String[] { "Ägare", "Streckkod", 
            "Färg", "Märke", "Ram-nummer", "Senast hämtad", "Senast lämnad" }) {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    bikeTable.setSelectionMode(0);
    bikeTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    JScrollPane tablePane = new JScrollPane(bikeTable);
    frame.add(tablePane);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void displayUsers(){
    tablePane.setViewportView(userTable);
}

public void displayBikes(){
    tablePane.setViewportView(bikeTable);
}
```

Comment: I never fill them becoause the parts that will provide the content isn't done yet. Is that the problem that is has to be filled?

Comment: The problem is that you initialize a local variable `tablePane` in your method instead of the class member. Remove the `JscrollPane`in front of your `tablePane` in your method (and of course leave it in front of your class member)

Comment: if you don't fill properly all the rows/columns of your data, you could indeed get lots of problems. Try initializing them all to dummy data.

Comment: Thats what happend when you copy paste too much I guesss :) Yeah I will fill them if stuff gets really bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView(yourNewTable);
```

This should replace the component displayed in the scroll pane. Of course you can always change the model of your JTable and its columns but that would not be my preference.

EDIT: Here is a snippet demonstrating this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final Vector<String> string = new Vector<String>();
        final JTable table = new JTable(getTableModel("First", 1));
        final JTable table2 = new JTable(getTableModel("Second", 3));
        final JButton click = new JButton("Click me");
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (table2.getParent() == null) {
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(table2);
                } else {
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
                }
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(click, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static TableModel getTableModel(final String prefix, final int colCount) {
        return new TableModel() {

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return prefix + "Hello cell (" + rowIndex + "," + columnIndex + ")";
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return 30;
            }

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
                return "Column " + columnIndex;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return colCount;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return String.class;
            }

            @Override
            public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: I got a NullPointerException. It displays the other table if I do scrollPane = new JScrollPane(otherTable) instead of scrollPane = new JScrollPane(currentTable). Switching between them doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex you need to show us more code then. All I can tell you is that this is the way to go. If needed, I'll provide an example of that.

Comment: I don't see the value of maintaining 2 separate tables, so you can switch between them, when at any given time only one will be displayed. Defeats the purpose of MVC pattern.

Comment: @Nasir It does not defeat MVC pattern. The purpose would mainly be performance. When switching models, your recreate the whole table, rows, columns, etc... Here it's just a switch. You also maintain column size, order, sorts, etc... Plenty of reasons to keep it

Comment: Thanks for the example! I will check this out in more detail tonight :)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thanks. Yeah, double buffering makes sense for performance.

Comment: You are using a vector I am using an array of objects. Can that be the cause?

Comment: @Alex No, because I am not even using the Vector in question (it is some kind of left-over from previous sample code). Consider posting the code where the problem occurs and make sure to show on which line the exception occur, with a comment on that line or something like that (we don't have line numbers on SO)

Comment: I did and the exeption is at the line with with tablePane.setViewportView(someTable). It depends on which method you call. Also this is a test so I use empty matrices for now.

Comment: BTW, I notice you have made all your GUI elements final. What is the benefit of this?

Comment: @Alex in this case: none. This is only a shortcut for my small example. By making it final, I make it also accessible for any of the inner-classes I wrote, here the ActionListener. If you don't know about `final`, you should consider looking into this. It can be very handy sometimes

Answer (score 2):

If you change the underlying model, it should work.

```
table.setModel(newModel)
```

and you may need to update the renderer too, if you are doing special things for certain cells/columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are maintaining two jTables (with two models), then perhaps the easiest way is to simply set the scrollpane's viewport:

```
jscrollpane.setViewportView(mySecondJTable);
```

and then to switch back:

```
jscrollpane.setViewportView(myFirstJTable);
```

Comment: Ah, looks like Guillaume just beat me to it with the same answer!